# Regex: how to separate parsed elements without mixing the output

Tags: python, sql, regex, regex-group, python-re

I have the following two use cases of parsing an expression inside a SQL query:

1. `[some_date:week]` should result in `week`. `week` here is one of a few keywords that are known in advance.
2. `[some_expression|condition]` should result in `1` or any other unrelated character, doesn't matter here.

I first came up with a following regex:

```
r"\[(.*)\:(sec|min|hour|day|date|week|month|year|aggregate)\]"
```

However, it is not working properly when there's multiple occurrences of such an expression.

I then only found a way to limit the length of expressions inside brackets using `{,30}` so for the second use case it becomes:

```
r"\[.{,30}\|.{,30}\]"
```

I don't feel that this is an optimal way to do it and looking forward to your suggestions!

Edit: here's some examples of how it works now and how it should work.

```
txt = """select [first:week] as time,
                [next:month] as date
         from table""" 

exp = r"\[(.*)\:(sec|min|hour|day|date|week|month|year|aggregate)\]"

print(re.sub(exp, r"\1", txt, flags = re.S|re.I))
    
>>  select first:week] as time,
           [next as date
    from table
```

Should be:

```
    select first as time,
           next as date
    from table
```

Comment: Can you add some examples with the expected output? Especially the cases where your regex does not work as expected.

Comment: IMHO  I think you should use sql parser if the input is dynamic

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: Only because regexs may backfire if there is a **nested sql query** or **inner queries** and all. That is why it is always suggested that you should use parsers for sql queries; HTML and XML, XSLT's, etc. Please use [sql-parse](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library whic is good for these purposes. Although if it is ensured that the structure of SQL query input always remains the same then; regexs can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r"\[([^][:]*):(sec|min|hour|day|date|week|month|year|aggregate)]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o6cpnA/1).

The main point is to use `[^][:]*` - any zero or more characters other than `]`, `[` and `:` - instead of `.*`.

Note that `.*?` won't work here either: if there is a non-matching substring between two matching ones, the first match [will be longer](https://regex101.com/r/o6cpnA/2) than expected.